# Lua: Read userdata as number / Compare userdata with number

Tags: input, lua, torch, matio

I am trying to import numbers from files and change them if they are at a certain value. I am using torch to get values form `gesture` and change them from `101` to `10` or from `100` to `9` if the input is the corresponding number (10 or 9). Unfortunately, I have figured out that in Lua, the input is of type `userdata` which cannot be converted to integers and not compared to integers or torch tensors.

So my question is: How can I check for equality of numbers if the input type is `userdata`?

Is there potentially a way to convert the input to a number such that comparison is possible?

```
gesture = matio.load(val, 'gesture')

print(type(gesture)) --prints `userdata`
print(gesture)       --prints 10 (for example)
if gesture == th.FloatTensor({101}) then
    gesture = th.FloatTensor({10})
    print("101 Detected! New value is: ")
    print(gesture)
    os.exit(0)
elseif gesture == th.FloatTensor({100}) then
    gesture = th.FloatTensor({9})
    print("100 Detected! New value is: ")
    print(gesture)
    os.exit(0)
end
```

Comment: Presumably, that userdata has member functions, right? Does one of these members not generate an integer?

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks a lot for the swift comment! :) I searched for `lua userdata member functions` before but did not see anything useful... any link you can refer me to?

Comment: You misunderstand. That userdata came from some C API. You should look at that API's documentation to learn how to use that userdata. There is no single API for userdata. Every C API exposes different functions for their various userdata objects.

Comment: @NicolBolas, so I was able to identify member functions, and tested out a few ones, but functions like `eq` only seem to compare object references, and the ones that seemed appropriate (from the name) do not work.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, so I had quite an extensive look, and couldn't find anything aroung the `matio` library as of this repo `https://github.com/soumith/matio-ffi.torch`. Any ideas for hacks etc. that might work? I wondered if it's possible to put these values into hashed and maybe compare hashes, but I'm not sure if that's possible in lua..

Comment: How do you expect to use a library whose interface you don't understand? Whatever Matio is, it must have some documentation, right?

Comment: I didn't choose the data format, nor the number of libraries existent to read Matlab files. I haven't found any useful documentation unfortunately, only some snippets.

Comment: Can't you call `:float()` on the gesture to retrieve the value?

Comment: Find the newest version of MATIO and its documentation here: https://github.com/tbeu/matio

Answer (score 4):

Just found an easier way

```
    local gesture_int = gesture:uint()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly complex question and after testing through the hard way, I found a way to compare the userdata number with an integer.

```
print(type(gesture)) -> prints `userdata`
print(gesture) -> 10
gesture_str = tostring(gesture)
print(type(gesture_str)) -> prints `string`
gesture_int = tonumber(gesture_str)
print(type(gesture_int)) -> prints `number`
```

Single line solution is as follows

```
gesture_int = tonumber(tostring(gesture))
```

This new variable stores the userdata number as an integer.